# Similar power merge

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

How can I tell Mathematica to write

```
{x^z1*y^(-a1 - z1 - z4)*z^(-a1 - z1 - z4)}
```

as (x/y)^(z1)*(y*z)^(-z4)
I mean combining terms with similar power?

Comment: Do you want `Simplify[{x^z1*y^(-a1 - z1 - z4)*z^(-a1 - z1 - z4)}]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way might be

```
Clear["Global`*"];
expr      = x^z1*y^(-a1 - z1 - z4)*z^(-a1 - z1 - z4);
exponents = Cases[expr, Power[y_, Plus[x_]] :> List @@ x];
exponents = Union@Flatten[exponents]

c = Cases[expr, Power[y_, Plus[x_]] :> If[MatchQ[Head[x], Plus | Times], 
           {y, #} & /@ (List @@ x), {{y, x}}]
    ];

c = Flatten[c, 1];
r = Function[{x}, Select[c, #[[2]] == x &]] /@ exponents;
r = (Times @@ (#[[All, 1]])^#[[1, 2]]) & /@ r
```

[image]

Now here is the issue. If we were to multiply these up, Mathematica will get in the middle and simplify things back to

```
 Times @@ r
```

[image]

To prevent this, and for display only

```
r = Defer[#] & /@ r;
Times @@ r
```

[image]